# reflect.DeepEqual not working on timestamp comparison

Tags: go

I am trying to write a test case to compare timestamps in golang. The problem is that reflect.DeepEqual is not able to check whether 2 timestamps are equal:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timestamp1, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2021-08-03T07:26:34Z")
    timestamp2 := time.Unix(0, int64(time.Millisecond)*timestamp1.UnixMilli())

    fmt.Printf("are both timestamps equal: %v", reflect.DeepEqual(timestamp1, timestamp2))
}
```

Could anyone tell me what might be going wrong in this comparison?

Comment: Don't use reflect, use the [`Time.Equal`](https://pkg.go.dev/time@go1.20.2#Time.Equal) method instead.

Comment: Comparing structs, timestamps are one of the fields of the struct. So, I think I might need DeepEqual.

Comment: There are multiple representations of the same moment.  reflect.DeepEqual has no way of knowing that. time.Equal does.

Comment: Do you suggest using string representation of time instead in the struct?

Comment: No. Use time.Equal as suggested. Twice.

Comment: There are likely 3rd party packages that will compare the structs the way you expect them to be compared, if you can't find such packages then you can write the functionality yourself, it's a better option than using string representation of time.

Comment: I could have, but time.Equal can't compare 2 variables of the same struct having time stamp in one of fields. Think of a test case in which you would want to compare 2 objects having a timestamp field

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Let me share a go.dev/play link with you, let me see if it actually supports writing unit tests

Comment: If you're writing unit tests, avoid reflect.DeepEqual. It's very unfriendly for tests.  Consider using this instead: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp

Comment: Just an update, `timestamp.UTC()` works! I think it might be trying to create `time.Time` in local timezone when using `time.Unix()` function.

Comment: @PrakharMishra: of course we can run the code, but there's no need to because can already see what it will do. Go can check equality just fine, which is what it's doing, but the problem is that two different, unequal time values can refer to the same instant -- that is what `Equal` is for, and the documentation clearly states that is what you should use.

Comment: @JimB, let me get this straight, there are many languages which have came before go and have implemented a way to check equality, and they did way better job. All you have to do is have an interface with Equals method, just like MarshalJSON, and all these problems would have gone away. Also, its not like I found the reflect package on my own, there are several articles suggesting the usage of the same broken method.

Comment: yes, there have been many other, different languages. Phrases like "All you have to do", "just", and "all these problems would have gone away" are highly loaded and don't take into account the differences between languages or the reasons for their design decisions.

Comment: "All you have to do is have an interface with Equals method [...] and all these problems would have gone away." Unfortunately no. Equality is a beast and behaves nasty on the edges (and its core is still under exploration).

Answer (score 3):

> Could anyone tell me what might be going wrong in [...] reflect.DeepEqual [...] timestamp comparison

`reflect.DeepEqual` reports whether two things are deeply equal, it doesn't care about "timestamps". Several "timestamps" representing the same instance in time might (actually do) have different representations as a `time.Time`.

You cannot use `reflect.DeepEqual` to compare `time.Time` values if you are interested in comparing the "timestamp" or instance in time that a `time.Time` represents. You *must* redesign, there is no way to force `reflect.DeepEqual` to do what you want.

Comment: `timestamp.UTC()` works, just for your information.

Comment: @PrakharMishra: `UTC()` only appears to work, but you still have the problem of monotonic clock skew. You must use `Equal` or a another time representation.